# passing array into boost vector tuple

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, lambda, tuples

I am finding nearest points for a given over million points using boost lambda library. When those million points are being read from text, it is working well. But to reduce the time of compilation I have stored those data inside the array and I am trying that code should read it from array. Although there is no compilation error, But the results are wrong with garbage value stored inside each element of the tuple. The code is:

```
  namespace 
  {
  typedef double coord_t;
  typedef boost::tuple<coord_t,coord_t,coord_t,coord_t,coord_t,coord_t> point_t;
```

Calculating distance using boost library:

```
  coord_t distance_sq(const point_t& a, const point_t& b) 
  { 
    boost::geometry::distance
    coord_t x = a.get<0>() - b.get<0>();
    coord_t y = a.get<1>() - b.get<1>();
    coord_t z = a.get<2>() - b.get<2>();
    return x*x + y*y + z*z;
   }
```

Input point from which nearest points to be found from million points:

```
  double px, py, pz; 
  px=4; py=4; pz=4;//-0.1958            0.8703          0.09787 
  point_t point(px, py, pz);

   }
```

Reading data from text file:

```
    ifstream f("MiniRotorCraft_02.txt");
    while(f)
    {
        coord_t xa,ya,za,ua,va,wa;
        f >> xa >> ya >> za >> ua >> va >> wa;     
        points.push_back(boost::make_tuple(xa,ya,za,ua,va,wa));//Million points entry into boost tuple
    }
```

When I am doing this it is working very well. But I wish my code not to read from text file but to read from set of arrays from the code itself. So I have written:

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < B[llp].size(); i++)  
    {
            xa[i]=get<0>(B[llp][i]); 
            ya[i]=get<1>(B[llp][i]);
            za[i]=get<2>(B[llp][i]);
            ua[i]=get<3>(B[llp][i]);
            va[i]=get<4>(B[llp][i]);
            wa[i]=get<5>(B[llp][i]);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < B[llp].size(); i++) 
    {
            coord_t xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i];
    //Instead of taking the data from text file I am trying to take from array that are stored in the code.   
            points.push_back(boost::make_tuple(xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i]));
    }
```

But it is not working. It is returning some arbitrary garbage value.
    How can it be done. Any suggestion shall be very much beneficial.

Comment: Is `B[llp]` your "points" array?
And what did you try to say by putting `coord_t xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i];` into your second loop?

Comment: Hallo! Kit. Thanks for your reply. B[llp] is a container which contains coordinates and velocities. Actually, I apologize at first my question was not clear and I updated it now. coord_t is basically a typedef , and point_t is a tuple of coord_t s, and points is a vector of point_t.

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < B[llp].size(); i++) 
{
        coord_t xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i];
//Instead of taking the data from text file I am trying to take from array that are stored in the code.   
        points.push_back(boost::make_tuple(xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i]));
}
```

isn't C++ standard because with

```
  coord_t xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i];
```

you're declaring 6 C-style arrays of `coord_t` (aka `double`) of size `i` where `i` is a run-time known value (a index in a loop).

But there is more: if the compiler accept to initialize C-style arrays with run-time values (some of they accept this as a language extension), they are not initialized (so with undefined values) and in the following line

```
points.push_back(boost::make_tuple(xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i]));
```

you're passing the value of index `i` (the i+1-nth values) of initialized C-style arrays of size `i`.

Conclusion: your program is undefined behavior and the garbage absolutely comprehensible.

Suspect: are you sure that you want the line

```
  coord_t xa[i],ya[i],za[i],ua[i],va[i],wa[i];
```

and that you don't want push the values obtained in the preceding `for`-loop ?